# Can I share game screens with other Unity programs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm going to ask you a question because there's something blocked while I was creating a VR program with Unity.

There is program A and program B.

A is a game program.

B is a monitoring program.

So the screen that A is running (main camera, sub-camera)

You must be able to see it at B.

The solution I thought would be

1. Calling up Unity Game Screens in Visual Studio
2. Sync the game screen itself over the network

I've tried both.

Number 1 shows the main camera, but I don't think I can see the sub-camera.

No. 2 is not syncing at all. I can connect.

So I'm wondering if there's another solution. Mr. Unity, please help me.

Comment: @Programmer I think you're the closest thing to "Mr. Unity" we've got, please help!

Comment: How are you syncing the game screen?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/what's your use-case?  If you just want to mirror what's in the headset, I thought Unity did that natively (at least, it does for me)?

Comment: Oh, you said over network...  IMHO, you'd need to look into stream encoding via something like OBS or shadowplay.  You could possibly do something with RenderTextures and sending frames, but would not recommend it except as last resort.